# How to programmatically determine the document root in PHP?

Tags: php, apache, configuration

Here's a problem that I've been running into lately - a misconfigured apache on a webhost. This means that all scripts that rely on `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` break. The easiest workaround that I've found is just set the variable in some global include files that is shared, but it's a pain not to forget it. My question is, how do I determine the correct document root programatically?

For example, on one host, the setup is like this:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] == '/htdocs'
```

The real document roots are:

```
test.example.com -> /data/htdocs/example.com/test
www.example.com -> /data/htdocs/example.com/www
```

And I'd like a script that's run from `www.example.com/blog/` (on the path `/data/htdocs/example.com/www/blog`) to get the correct value of `/data/htdocs/example.com/www`.

On another host, the setup is a bit different:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] == '/srv'
test.example.com -> /home/virtual_web/example.com/public_html/test
www.example.com -> /home/virtual_web/example.com/public_html/www
```

Is there any solution to this? Or is the only way simply not to ever rely on `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and fix all the software that I'm running on my sites? Fixing this on the hosting's side doesn't seem to be an option, I've yet to encounter a host where this is was configured correctly. The best I got was a document root pointing to www.example.com, which was at least inside open_basedir - they used yet another naming scheme, www.example.com would point to `/u2/www/example_com/data/www/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on http://www.helicron.net/php/:

```
$localpath=getenv("SCRIPT_NAME");
$absolutepath=getenv("SCRIPT_FILENAME");
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']=substr($absolutepath,0,strpos($absolutepath,$localpath));
```

I had to change the basename/realpath trick because it returned an empty string on my host. Instead, I use `SCRIPT_FILENAME`. This probably won't work on IIS anymore (but the original scripts that used the $_SERVER variable probably wouldn't either).

Answer (score 7):

In PHP5 there is the magic constant `__FILE__` that contains the absolute path of the file in which it appears. You can use it in combination with dirname to calculate the document root.

You can put a statement like the following one in a config file

```
define ('DOCUMENT_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
```

this should do the trick

Comment: The trick was using both the absolute name of the file (either from the magic constant, or from the server vars) and combine it with the knowledge of the absolute path realtive to the document root from SCRIPT_NAME.

Comment: From PHP 5.3 this is also `__DIR__` use that in stead of `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Comment: But this just returns the folder of the current file which is not necessarily the actual root folder of the webserver.

Comment: Yes @Chuck, you are right, but, if you cannot rely on the $server configuration (I would not do rely on all its values it if not really forced) and do not have a const in place you have to resort to a workaround. The one I proposed is intendet to solve, better to give an hint toward the solution, of this very specific case.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to modify all scripts.

You can run PHP file before any script is run using [`auto_prepend_file`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php).

`$_SERVER` is just an array, you *can* modify it and set correct `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

Comment: That is kindof useless to run that script on *every run.

Comment: That is kindof useless to run that script on *every* run.
Better handle it with some .htaccess instead of setting it.

Comment: You can use php_value in .htaccess to set auto_prepend_file, but author of the question had mentioned IIS server which I assume doesn't support this.

Comment: Actually, I don't care about IIS, it's just that the original solution was supposed to be "platform independent", and I'm not sure if it still works afterwards. But that auto prepend sure looks interesting, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

This is one reason why people siphon everything through a bootstrap /index.php using htaccess and/or query strings. You can use the `dirname( __FILE__ )` trick noted above and get the public base of your app that way.

If you're too far into it to switch to a single entry point, one thing I've seen people do is have a common header to their script which walks up the directory tree to find a file which is unique to the base dir:

```
function findAppBase( $dir ) {
    if( file_exists( "$dir/unique_file.txt" ) ) {
        return $dir;

    return findAppBase( dirname( $dir ) );
}

$base = findAppBase( dirname( __FILE__ ) );
```

That code hasn't been tested, and there might be a slicker way using the vars in `$_ENV` or `$_SERVER` that will do what you want...

Comment: Thankfully, this isn't a problem, I do have only a single entry point. It's just that I run the same software on multiple domains and hosts, and I have to fix it for each domain. I'd rather submit a fix upstream so I don't have to care about it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

PHP *should* be setting the current directory to the one the script is in, so as long as that's not broken you should be able to figure out the document root using `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` and `getcwd()`. (I can't remember all the $_SERVER vars off the top of my head, there might be something in phpinfo() that's more useful.)

Comment: Some scripts I've installed are "too smart" and know which directory (relative to the theoretical document root) they're installed in, and append this to the document root (after they got it from the database). I'd still have to modify the code for each directory to strip the directories... or not?

Answer (score 0):

Why not demand that your webhost configures his servers correctly?

these kind of things tend to linger silently in your code and never get removed (but still active) until someone finally fixes the server. Thén everything will break again.

Or, move your stuff to a host that will work. If this is broken, who knows what you will find next.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible to configure the host correctly, it's seems to be a problem with mod_vhost_alias (according to a comment on http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3640691.htm).