# is there a better way to go back to the directory root other than using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?

Tags: php, document-root

I'm trying to learn a better way to go back to the root directory. I heard that using $_SERVER isn't the safest way. Im wondering if there is a better way.
so i could get something like this on the url example.com/exp/my.php

here's what i got.

```
include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cpages/cmain/func/init.php');
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cpages/toppart.php');
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cpages/boxes/image.php');
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cpages/bottonpart.php');
```

I change it to

```
define ('DOCUMENT_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
include (DOCUMENT_ROOT.'/cpages/cmain/func/init.php');
include(DOCUMENT_ROOT.'/cpages/toppart.php');
include(DOCUMENT_ROOT.'/cpages/boxes/image.php');
include(DOCUMENT_ROOT.'/cpages/bottonpart.php');
```

but now it's giving me a error

```
Warning: include(C:\xampp\htdocs\backbone\image/cpages/cmain/func/init.php)
```

and `($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` didn't gave it me that error is their a way to fix it ?

Comment: Why would [`$_SERVER`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)`['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` be unsafe?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390276/how-to-programmatically-determine-the-document-root-in-php

Comment: @JonathonReinhart not sure but its better of looking for a safer way you kno

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you can't rely on anthing in the $_SERVER array, as it's possible to you may get all sorts of values.

So you'll need the following rules:

1. If writing public code, put the path in a config file. Then if $_SERVER is not right on the user's server, they can overwrite it. You can help pre-complete their config using `DOCUMENT_ROOT` if you like using some simple rules (see below).
2. If writing code for your own use that's only going to hop between a server or two, then assume `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is correct, and rwwrite it if you move servers and need to.

---

How to provide the default `DOCUMENT_ROOT` if pre-compiling a config variable.

1. On Apache, check `CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT`. `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is nearly always safe, but there are a couple of places where it can be wrong - and that's the case in the link you provided. If apache is using mod_alias or mod user_dir. In these cases, you need to use `CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT` which is safer. But note that Apache has only been adding `CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT` for a month or so, so unless you have the very latest install, you need to fall back on `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.
2. `DOCUMENT_ROOT` - see above
3. Use `PATH_TRANSLATED` (less the length of `PHP_SELF`) to contruct a path to current working directory.
4. Use `SCRIPT_FILE_NAME` (less the length of `PHP_SELF`) to contruct a path to current working directory.
5. Use the global variable `__DIR__`  to current working directory

Then, when you have those details, check for a file you know exists in that directory - and if it does, you've probably got the right path. If not, try the next one along.