# How to get the base installation path of a web application

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to programmatically determine the document root in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390276/how-to-programmatically-determine-the-document-root-in-php)

If a user extracted my web application to `/var/www/webapp/`, `/var/www` being the `DocumentRoot` (so the application would be accessed over `example.tld/webapp/`), what's the best way to get the installation path `/webapp/`?
I need this because I got to know about the full absolute URI at some pages of my service.

Comment: `__DIR__` in any file that's located in that directory

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390276/how-to-programmatically-determine-the-document-root-in-php

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the `__DIR__` constant.

Comment: Yeah, my phone's keyboard took out the underscores.

Comment: you need to put backticks "`" around

Comment: Well how am I going to get just the `/webapp/` part now? This is what I need to know, not the full machine-directory.

Comment: Do some logic, get a substring of what's between the first / you encounter (going backwards) and the end of the string.